# Can we create a link with dynamic ID in SPA model

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, single-page-application, multi-page-application

I am developing a single page application using ReactJS. My whole application is running in Single Page. Now, I need one page that accept the used ID from the URL and show the result based on the user ID.
Is this possible in SPA model or I have to move the my website to MPA model?

I tried some answers and am not clear about it

for ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/id/101

I have to get the ID 101 and show the result based on the id in the page.

Comment: Sorry... I don't get you

Comment: The question which you have referenced in your question isn’t found

Comment: I referenced this one: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/73 but I am not clear with this answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes sure this is possible.

Let me give you some background over this. If you are building SPA with multiple pages, you would like to use a client-side routing in otder to display differen page based on the browser url. As I know defacto solution for routing in react is [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web) but there are many other to chose from. [See this link](https://reactjs.org/community/routing.html). Unfortunately, I won't be able to completely explain how to use `react-router` solution, but here is a brief example.

Inside your main component (like App.jsx) add routing:

```
// 1. do proper imports
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

// 2. wrap your application inside of BrowserRouter component

class App extends React.Component {
// your code

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                {/* your app code */}

                {/* Add routing */}
                <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
                <Route path="/questions/id/:id" component={Question} />

                {/* your app code */}
            <BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
```

You should see now that when your browser url matches `/questions/id/:id` component `Question` should be mounted to the page. Inside this component, you can fetch `id` that was passed in. It will be inside `this.props.match.param.id` property

```
class Question extends React.Component {
// your code

    render() {
        const id = this.props.match.param.id;        

        return (
            <div>
                Page with { id } was opened
            <div>
        )
    }
}
```

Sure you would like to familiarise yourself with `react-router` docs.

Answer (score 0):

ReactJs don't include a router. But the most popular package to do this is React-router.
The official documentation references [other good packages](https://reactjs.org/community/routing.html)

Comment: It would be great if anyone add the specfic example for this.

Comment: If you read all references on the previous link, there is many example with dynamic route, for example : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params.